# Ubuntu 20.04 doesnt start since apt upgrade

Tags: boot, apt, grub2, 20.04, bios

I have an old notebook with dual-boot and legacy BIOS. Win10 installed first, then Ubuntu 20.04. I have made an "apt upgrade" on 13.05.2020 Wed. Normal Shutdown after that. Unfortunately Ubuntu doesn't boot since then. Win10 still works. Fsck is started, but nothing others appear. (Please see also screenshots)

What I have already tried without result:

- tried to boot with older kernel
- tried to boot with recovery and repair packages & repair grub
- tried to reinstall grub (&update-grub)
- tried to repair apt/dpkg packages with the help of this site: https://www.ostechnix.com/how-to-fix-broken-ubuntu-os-without-reinstalling-it/

Do you have any more hints? Thank you!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you remember if Win 10 did any updates/upgrades on or after 13th or between working Ubuntu and you had trouble booting Ubuntu

Comment: No, Win10 didnt trigger any updates since then.

Answer (score 0):

fricigrillbufe --unless wanting to compile only bug reports--

"Note that the recommended upgrade process currently displays the announcement of the development release" --might be Microsoft's conclusive  hint.

[Ubuntu Focal Fossa (20.04) LTS is now released, and posts about it are (generally) No Longer Offtopic](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19044/ubuntu-focal-fossa-20-04-lts-is-now-released-and-posts-about-it-are-generall?cb=1)

hope well 
–

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the problem and solved the issue! :)

I found in the /var/log/Xorg.0.log that there is problem with nvidia driver. I removed all nvidia packages. (sudo apt-get purge nvidia*) Then installed this package: nvidia- where xyz is the highest available number.

I used this post as inspiration:
[Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)